# @HTML.Raw with a variable parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-parameters, actionresult

I have an MVC view that has dropdowns and buttons for selecting customers etc. There is also a create email button to create a custom email for the selected customer. THere is a view to create customer email. When the Create view loads from a button ActionResult view, the Createview does not filter it's own Customer dropdown to Select the chosen Customer.

The dropdown on the Customers page has the customer select dropdpwn (in the ready function) and a button to load the create page. Here is what I am trying:

```
   $("#Customer_Id")
            .change(function(e) {
                customerId = $('#Customer_Id').val();
                oEmployeesTable.fnDraw();

                var cust = "/" + $('#Customer_Id').val();
                url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Create", "CustomerEmail", "' + cust +'"))';
            });


<script type="text/javascript">
function CreateCustEmail() {
    alert(url);
    //window.location = url;
}
```

I have 'var url;' declared at global level.  Any help would be really welcome.... Thank you

Comment: You're mixing serverside and clientside code. `@Html` helpers run when the page is rendered on the server, the JavaScript code runs in the browser.

Comment: That is why I was creating the javascript to try and load the create view page again, but with a 'selected' ClientId being passed to it. And although Urvish's answer gave the correct URL, it didn't cause the controller to be loaded for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var cust = "/" + $('#Customer_Id').val();
url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Create", "CustomerEmail", new { your variable = "cust"}))'; 
url = url.replace("cust", cust);
```

try it...if it wil be help for you

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it looked ok, but... The url it created was

    http://localhost:54999/CustomerEmail/Create?CustomerId=1005

which looks ok, but the controller was not loaded

Comment: Actually, I was using with "@url.routeurl" in my project in jqury. its working well, i think You got this problem by @html.raw You should change something in it. and Yea, you want to load this url then write last line                      "window.location.href = url" i hope that it will helpful

Comment: Hi Urvish...  You were absolutely spot on, and it is all working great now. I missed the breakpoint in the controller... I knew there had to be something missing as what you gave me before gave me the right URL. So thank you so much Urvish... All working well now :)